# How to get previous page's URL in Salesforce

Tags: visualforce

Suppose I am redirected from page 1 to page 2 due to some action performed on VF page . I am looking for a way to use a hyper link in page 2 clicking on that will redirect me back to page 1 . Anyone can help me out with some hints!! thanks.

Comment: Please try to use tags with a close relation to the content of your question.

Answer (score 7):

For standard pages Salesforce implemented a nice pattern: when redirecting the source page passes parameter `retURL` that tells the target page where to return. For example when you choose to *Edit* a contact from the account layout, Salesforce takes you to

```
https://<instance>.salesforce.com/<Contact ID>/e?retURL=%2F<Account ID>
```

and redirects back to the account after saving changes or canceling.

The `retURL` param can be easily accessed from both APEX:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL')
```

and VisualForce:

```
{!$CurrentPage.Parameters.retURL}
```

BTW when getting `retURL` in apex you should enclose ist in a try catch block. Becuase sometimes a user can directly go to that page in which case there will be no `retURL`. If an exceptio0n occurs then it means that no `retURL` parameter is present then you can just redirect to page you want by creating a custom `PageReference`.e.g. `new PageReference('/home/home.jsp');`

Of course there are other options, for example playing with [HTTP Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer).

Comment: Hi Endrju...I need to get the previous page for a VF page and I am trying to access this value in APEX code .So, should I go ahead with {!$CurrentPage.Parameters.retURL}? Could you pls specify how to get the value of 'retURL' ?

Comment: From the APEX code you should go with the first option: `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL')`. `ApexPages.currentPage.getParameters()` simply gives an access to all parameters passed through URL.

Comment: Hi, my base URL is - https://c.cs10.visual.force.com/apex/myPage?id=a2NJ00000003OqO.   After some illegal action I am showing an error message to the user and there I kept a hyperlink to the error message added at apex pagemessage section. At this also the URL is same as base url..Only refreshing the browser is able to show me the base record..Pls suggest how to inject the refresh browser code in my hyperlink of error message.